# Al llamar a una funcion(Uncaught ReferenceError. Is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema cuando llamo a la funcion **mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad()**.
Antes solo tenia los dos parametros primeros, pero al añadir el tercero **data.nombre** me da el siguiente error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: MADRID is not defined
    at :1:52*
Esta función recoge los parametros:

```
function mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(id_localid, cat, nombrePoblacion)
```

*Estos valores estaria recogiendo la funcion:*
mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(29077,45,MADRID)

¿Me podeis arrojar algo de luz, por favor?.

```
$.ajax({
        data: params,
        url: 'adminasesmed/obtenerlugares.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            var cat;
            cat = getUrlVars();
            var data;   
            /*Liampiamos el div antes de ejecutar otra busqueda*/
            $("#localidades").html("");     
            /*Volvemos a llenar el div*/                        
            var html =  "<ul style=''>";
            $.each(response, function(index, data){                                                                                                     
                html += "<li><a style='display: block;color: #000;padding: 8px 16px;text-decoration: none; :hover background-color: #555;color: white' href='javascript:mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(" + data.id_localidad + "," + cat + "," + data.nombre + ")'>" + data.nombre + " - (" + data.codigoProvinciaAsesmed + ")</a><li>";
                console.log(html);
            });
            html += "</ul>"
            $("#localidades").append(html);                             
        }
    })
```

Comment: El error dice que MADRID es una funcion y no esta definida, posiblemente sea una llave mal cerrada

Comment: Es raro @Kevin, porque si quito esto `+ "," + data.nombre` funciona. Es al añadir el tercer parametro. No entiendo, por qué.

Comment: ¿Estás pasando MADRID sin comillas? Si es el caso se interpretará como una variable y, si no existe obviamente obtendrás un *ReferenceError*.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía es que no se como pasarlo con comillas simples ya que seria un tercer nivel de comillas.¿Sabes como hacerlo?. Gracias

Comment: ¿Intentaste con backslash? https://repl.it/JbBt

Comment: He probado así @GustavoGarcía: `'javascript:mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(" + data.id_localidad + "," + cat + ",'" + \'data.nombre\' + ")'` pero no me funciona.

Comment: `"javascript:mostrarproductosporlocalidadyespecialidad(" + data.id-localidad + "," + cat + "'" + data.nombre + "')";`

Comment: Gracias @GustavoGarcía. Al final funcionó :)

Comment: Si gustas elimina tu pregunta porque *puede considerarse* un error tipográfico. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Así como está tu código MADRID lo toma como una variable que lleva el nombre MADRID, si lo que quieres es que tome el string MADRID escríbelo como tal, así "MADRID" así el parámetro es una valor y no una variable no definida.

Comment: Pero no veo como meter esas comillas, porque sería un tercer nivel de comillas y escapandolas no me funciona o no lo hago bien.

Comment: De acuerdo con lo que leí [aquí] (http://mozillaes.org/foros/viewtopic.php?t=4332) puedes usar una barra invertida (alt+92)

Comment: No veo manera de hacerlo. He probado de escapar las comillas de todas las formas posibles y nada :(